# Road Graph plugin routing on a virtual numeric field does not work

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, routing

I'm trying to calculate the shortest/fastest path based on a 'dynamic' virtual field with the road graph plugin.  The speedvalues are based on a combination of other ppvalues: eg field GFBscore.
[image]

But when I want to select GFBscore as the speed field in vector > road graph > settings it does not show up in the dropdown list

[image]

Is this due to a bug or do I have to make a feature request somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RoadGraph is older than virtual fields, the issue is most certainly that nobody has added support. You can add a feature request at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues/new and set the category to C++ plugins/roadgraph

Comment: OK, when I get acces to it, I add a request

Comment: on the next release (2.16) it will be fixed